# docker-compose up giving file not found error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vagrant, vagrant-ssh

I am using vagrant. when i do git bash in the folder which already contain docker-compose.yml file. but when i execute command docker-compose up then that gives me error like

```
ERROR:
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

steps i did :
 1. went in folder which contain vagrant and docker-compose.yml file
 2. right click and clicked on git bash here
 3. give command in git bash as vagrant ssh
 4. then give command as docker-compose up

Comment: You think that `folder [...] already contain docker-compose.yml file`. docker-compose thinks that: `Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory [...]  Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml`. You need to find why there is such a gap in your respective analyzes of the situation.

Comment: @Zeitounator how to i found that if docker-compose pointing to correct directory or not ?

Comment: You could for example `pwd` and `ls` before you launch to make sure you are in the correct dir.

Comment: @Zeitounator its giving home/user. how to point to directory which contains .yml file

Comment: by changing directory to where your docker-compose.yml file is or by passing its path to docker-compose with the `-f` option

Comment: @Zeitounator i tried giving docker-compose with file path and it gives error like - .FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './D:ProjectsGitHubvalde-valde-docker-composedocker-compose.yml'

Comment: That last error looks like you've swapped "\" for "/". Windows uses a different convention from Linux. Your base machine is Windows, but most Docker images use Linux conventions...  although I guess I'm over a year too late to help with that

Answer (score 5):

It could be that the docker service is down. You can check that with:

```sh
sudo systemctl status docker.service
```

If it's down you can use the following command to restart it.

```sh
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

Comment: "/usr/bin/systemctl": Cannot execute binary file is the error message I get while trying to run this inside the container

Comment: Well, if you're running this command inside a container, than the service is up, so probably is something else.

Answer (score -2):

point to the directory where ur yml file are .
in the yml file u have build line check it .
it that line u put the path of ur DockerFile .
and apply the command docker-compose up in the path of ur yml file .

Comment: i meant go to the directory where are u have created ur yml file . @RituChoudhari

Comment: i did that only and that file only it is giving file not found.. i tried this also docker-compose -f D:\Projects\GitHub\valde-valde-docker-compose\docker-compose.yml up -d and it gives me error - ERROR: .FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './D:ProjectsGitHubvalde-valde-docker-composedocker-compose.yml'

Comment: u have an error in ur path , check ur path carefully , and check ur build point in yml file .

1 - first go to that directory : D:\Projects\GitHub\valde-valde-docker-compose\ 
2 - open shell here 
3 - write in shell : docker-compose up -d 
@RituChoudhari